# Regular expression to validate input from 4 or 5 character the first 3 should be alwas letters

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I validate input: must be at least 4 character, and maximum 5 character. The last one is number, and the last 2 should be numbers. for example:

> WER4

or

> ASD23

Does it mean that the first 3 character should be always letters?

I don't know much about regex.

Comment: Your question does not include [any attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/10221765) at all to solve the problem. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should see Jon Skeet's [guide to writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get a free badge, and make sure to [search the site](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: I don't normally downvote "urgent" questions, but the combination of demanding something of volunteers for which no effort has been made merits more than just closure. Readers _want_ to help you, but you need to help yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression could look like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}$
```

- `^` is denoting the beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]` is a character class that includes all uppercase and lowercase letters from A to Z
- `{3}` requires three consecutive occurences of that aforementioned character class
- `[0-9]` is a character class that includes all numbers from 0 to 9
- `{1,2}` requires at least one, maximum two consecutive occurences of that character class
- `$` is denoting the end of the string

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}$" maxlength="5" required />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much, dose I need to make a test for the input or that's enough?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You should always additionally validate any user input server-side, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I mean do I need to match the user input with this regex or the form will never submit if it's not valid, I want the user to input his first 3 letters of his first name and date of birth could be one number or 2 like 9 or 23

Comment: In all modern browsers, the browser will not submit the form until the pattern is matched (or the user maliciously modifies or removes the pattern from the markup via browser dev tools). However, you should still always double-check on the server-side of things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this regex for set the string as 3 letters OR digits, and 1 or 2 digits:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{1,2}$
```

and if you want to set it to 3-4 letters OR digits and 1 digit, use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,4}\d$
```

If you want to try regexes by yourself you should use this site:
[regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: From the question: "the first 3 character should be always letters" (though it's not really clear because of the question mark at the end and the grammatical mistakes)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, just to make sure it's the right thing the user should input his first 3 letter of his name and the date of his birth might be one umber or 2 like 99 or 17

Comment: The first regex in my answer is exactly what you need. Be noticed that I edited it. Good Luck!